# Why does transition to page not work?

Tags: jquery, html

I wrote code that adds class *active* when navbar is clicked.

JS:

```
$(".nav li a").on('click', function(e) {                                                                                                               
    $(".nav .active").removeClass('active');                                                                                                            
    console.log($(this));                                                                                                                               
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');                                                                                                                
    e.preventDefault();                                                                                                                                 
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">                                                                                                                         
    <li><a href="/board/math">math</a></li>                                                                                                 
    <li><a href="/board/english">english</a></li>                                                                                                             
    <li><a href="/board/interstellar">interstellar</a></li>                                                                                                  
    <li><a href="/board/science">science</a></li>                                                                                                      
</ul>
```

If I click `li` tag, *active* class is added. But it can't work to move page for href link.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you don't want to prevent default behaviour for `<a>` (moving to `href` page), then what for did you add `e.preventDefault();`?

Comment: if I don't add e.preventDefault(), not working addclass 'active'

Comment: @hanjaelee do you want to keep the active class after the reload ?

Comment: @empiric yes, and then move to page for href link, But now, my code is not working to move page, it is situation that just add class 'active'

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname
$('.nav li a[href="'+pathname+'"]').addClass("active");
```

Since by clicking a link, the page is refreshed, you have to set the active class depending on the pathname that is in the url.

If you have some additional parameters in the url, you could do like this:

```
$('.nav li a[href^="'+pathname+'"]').addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your approach to the requirement.

There is no need to have a click handler, instead in dom ready you can do either

```
$('.nav li a[href$="'+window.location.pathname+'"]').addClass('active');
```

or

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
$('.nav li a').each(function(){
    return path.indexOf($(this).attr('href'))>-1
}).addClass('active');
```